# The volume of a sphere in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

Using the following formula for a sphere i tried to calculate the volume: $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ and using the fact that $x^2+y^2+z^2 =R^2$ \begin{align*}
\int\int\int x^2+y^2+z^2 dxdydz &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}\pi}\int_0^a R^2 \sin(\phi) R^2 dRd\phi\theta\\
&= \frac{4\pi}{5}a^5
\end{align*}
However the actual formula for volume is $\frac{4\pi}{3}a^3$ why does one R^2 disappear? One comes from the jacobian matrix and one from the $x^2+y^2+z^2 =R^2$.

Comment: Integral to find volume does not have $x^2+y^2+z^2$.  It's just $\int dV$.

Comment: Ofcourse it does, i could not figure it out for 4 hours. Thanks alot ( i feel silly now)

Comment: The area of a unit square, for example, is $\int_0^1\int_0^1 dydx$.